# VHDL SLV dynamic width slice assignment

Tags: vhdl, multiplexer, synthesis

I have some code that takes in 2^X samples and outputs 2^Y samples, where X and Y are integers and Y is less than X. So for example X=6,Y=4, I ingest 64 samples and output 16 samples.

As of right now, X and Y are generics, but I would like to make them, or the ratio between then, or the log2 of that ratio a signal, so that I might change my operation at runtime via a register write or something.

In my internal processing, using the example values of 64 and 16, I have to do some addressing and counting, and to generate some of the addresses I have to do soemthing like this:

```
constant pkt_addr_pad : std_logic_vector(15 -Y downto 0) := (others=>'0');
-- In this example is is 12 bits of 0
.
.
.
raddr_short <= pkt_addr_pad & raddr (Y-1 downto 0);
```

to convert raddr which can contain values from 0 to 63, to raddr_short which only contains values of 0 to 15; effectively discarding bits 4 and 5, masking them to 0, whatever you want to call it.

I'm looking for the best way to be able to have Y change at runtime. obviously the timing for Y is relaxed, as it changes unimaginably less frequently relative to the actual address, and when it does change, the rest of my logic will be in an idle state such that raddr/raddr short won't be changing

I'd really rather avoid the whole:

```
raddr_short <= x"00" & "00"  & raddr(5 downto 0) when Y = 6 else
               x"00" & "000" & raddr(4 downto 0) when Y = 5 else
               ....
               x"00" & "000000" & raddr(1 downto 0) when Y = 2 else
               x"0000";
```

as I've actually 4 of these things running at once, and as such have arrays of slv16 for each of the raddr/raddr_shorts, as well as waddrs, and...

Although I guess I could put the MUX in a function to clean up the code, but there has to be a better way. maybe some thing liek:

```
constant zeros16 : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := (others=>'0');
.
.
.
raddr_short <= zeros(15 downto Y) & raddr (Y-1 downto 0);
```

Comment: Just use a mask. Something like "mask <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(2**Y-1, mask'length));" and "raddr_short <= raddr and mask;".

Comment: Can you explain why this needs to be done at all? The only real benefit of this operation is that it *masks off the upper bits* of `raddr`. But do you need to? In your example, if `Y=4`, then would `raddr` ever get higher than 15 in the first place...?

Comment: @Mr.Snrub because on the input side of things, I ingest a packet of length X (in my example 64), and the counter in my process that generates addresses goes from 0 to 63, and on the output side I need only the lower X bits. that is to say that that I need to map 0 to 15 -> 0 to 15, 16 to 31 -> 0 to 15, 32 to 47 -> 0 to 15, and 48 to 63 -> 0 to 15. And I need both. Yes I could increment for 0 to 15, and then on 15 -> 0 have another counter increment, and then check for rolling over 3->0, but that is the same thing as having a 6 bit counter in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As of right now, X and Y are generics, but I would like to make them, or the ratio between then, or the log2 of that ratio a signal, so that I might change my operation at runtime via a register write or something.

Well, since you're implying that you're pretty flexible on how to get this done, then certainly the simplest approach would be to just have a register `mask` which you simply set to have `1` bits in the appropriate spots -- for example `"0000000000001111"` or `"0000000000111111"`. Then just apply the mask exactly like @JonathanDrolet suggests, i.e.:

```
raddr_short <= raddr and mask;
```

Advantage: super-simple to implement and to understand. Disadvantage: possible to set `mask` to values that could result in weird operation (but do you really care about "guard against bad user input" in your application)?

If you wanted to get fancier (but again, *why?*) then you could try the approach suggested by JonathanDrolet, but I'm doubtful that a synthesizer would be able to synthesize the construct `std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(2**Y-1, mask'length))` into a reasonable circuit, if it would synthesize at all. But you could use a hybrid approach: you say you have "4 of these things running at once" but if they all share the same `Y` value then you could calculate the `mask` once and apply it to all of them:

```
mask <= "0000000000111111" when Y = 6 else
        "0000000000011111" when Y = 5 else
        ...
        "0000000000000011" when Y = 2 else
        (others => '0');

raddr1_short <= raddr1 and mask;
raddr2_short <= raddr2 and mask;
...
```

If it were me, I'd still just go with the simpler programmable `mask` register, though.